# remoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(...) returns statusCode SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast, google-cast

I have a radio application which plays live radio stations on Google Chromecast. Starting a stream with remoteMediaPlayer.load(...) works just fine.
But `remoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(...)` for later stopping the stream says `statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` and throws a `IllegalStateException: No current media session`

Why can't I stop the playing live radio stream? Or how can I stop the remoteMediaPlayer playback?

The live radio streams are HTTP. Can it be the problem?

Here the details:

The following code starts the stream and it works.

```
    MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, stationName);
    mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(imageUrl)));
    final MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(stationUrl).setContentType("audio/mp3").setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
            .setMetadata(mediaMetadata).build();
    try {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(apiClient, mediaInfo, true).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(MediaChannelResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Utils.log(TAG, "Media loaded successfully: " + result.getStatus());
                } else {
                    Utils.log(TAG, "Media loaded NOT successfully: " + result.getStatus());
                }
            }
        });
    } catch .... {
```

The following code stops the stream and it does not work.
The result ist `statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` and `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current media session`

```
public static void stop() {
    try {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer.requestStatus(apiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                Status status = mediaChannelResult.getStatus();
                Utils.log(TAG, "RemoteMediaPlayer requestStatus: Status=" + status.getStatus());
                try {
                    mRemoteMediaPlayer.stop(apiClient);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception while stopping GoogleApiClient. ", e);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Problem occurred while geting requestStatus", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while geting requestStatus. ", e);
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
05-25 06:19:58.360: D/CastHelper(30561): RemoteMediaPlayer requestStatus: Status=Status{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null}
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561): Exception while stopping GoogleApiClient. 
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current media session
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.es.dC(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.es.b(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.cast.RemoteMediaPlayer$4.a(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.cast.RemoteMediaPlayer$4.a(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.a$b.b(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.a(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.b(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.cast.RemoteMediaPlayer.stop(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.cast.RemoteMediaPlayer.stop(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.mydomain.myapp.CastHelper$8.onResult(CastHelper.java:97)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.mydomain.myapp.CastHelper$8.onResult(CastHelper.java:1)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.a$c.b(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.a$c.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
05-25 06:19:58.360: E/CastHelper(30561):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

toString() isn't really a good way to get the status code. RemoteMediaPlayer has its own set of STATUS_* codes. SIGN_IN_REQUIRED is 4, which is RemoteMediaPlayer.STATUS_REPLACED which means that you issued another request of the same type as this request. The RemoteMediaPlayer, by design, will only track one request of each type. For example, if you send a PAUSE followed by another PAUSE before the first PAUSE request has completed (i.e., received a reply from the receiver), it will stop tracking the first PAUSE and report this error.

Comment: Thanks for point out that I "issued another request of the same type". I initialized the RemoteMediaPlayer to early in the application. Instantiating the RemoteMediaPlayer just before start playing solved my problem. Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want to use `stop` rather than, say `pause`? You can call `stop` but be aware that after calling `stop`, you need to re-attach media channel and then load the next media, that is why just using `pause` is more convenient in this case. If you want to load another stream, you don't need to call `pause` either; simply loading a second media while the first one is playing would work well.

Comment: `pause` would also be an option but is not working either. The error occurs even before pause - at `requestStatus`. I figured out that `load` works always well for the user but in the logs I see after the second time calling `load` also `statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`. Strange because the live streams work well and do not need sign in. Why does `load` work without breaking the app but `pause` or `stop` do not work - even they all get the same status `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`?? Where does `statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` come from? Thanks!