# Chromecast receiver using sendLoadComplete() doesn't update status

Tags: chromecast

I'm writing a Chromecast receiver to play different kind of contents (including embedded flash videos). I'd like to use my own JS library to create the player canvas, not to rely on the html video element.

I'm currently blocked because I can't get a media to be loaded using a custom behaviour :

## Receiver :

Nothing fancy in the HTML, I just load my library in the *#mediaWrapper* div. Then I create a *MediaManager* from it.

```
var node = $( "#mediaWrapper" )[0];
var phiEngine = new phi.media.Player( node );
window.mediaManager = new cast.receiver.MediaManager( phiEngine );
window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();

/* Override Load method */
window.mediaManager['origOnLoad'] = window.mediaManager.onLoad;
window.mediaManager.onLoad = function (event) {
    console.log('### Application Load ', event);

    /* Custom code (load lib, set metadata, create canvas ...) */

    window.mediaManager.sendLoadComplete(); // Doesn't seem to do anything

    // window.mediaManager['origOnLoad'](event);
    // -> Fails 'Load metadata error' since url is not a video stream
    // -> ex: youtube url
}

/* Will never be called */
window.mediaManager['origOnMetadataLoaded'] = window.mediaManager.onMetadataLoaded;
window.mediaManager.onMetadataLoaded = function (event) {
...
}
```

## Sender :

I use my own android application to cast to the device. I can't use the Companion library because it will be a *Titanium module*.

```
private void createMediaPlayer() {
    // Create a Remote Media Player
    mRemoteMediaPlayer = new RemoteMediaPlayer();
    mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener(
        new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusUpdated() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onStatusUpdated");

                }
            }
    });

    mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnMetadataUpdatedListener(
        new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnMetadataUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMetadataUpdated() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onMetadataUpdated");

            }
    });

    try {
        Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(mApiClient,
            mRemoteMediaPlayer.getNamespace(), mRemoteMediaPlayer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while creating media channel", e);
    }

    mRemoteMediaPlayer
    .requestStatus(mApiClient)
    .setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(MediaChannelResult result) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Request status : ", result.toString());
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to request status.");
                }
            }
    });
}


private void loadMedia( MediaInfo mediaInfo, Boolean autoplay ) {
    try {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, autoplay)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(MediaChannelResult result) {
                Log.e(TAG, "loadMedia ResultCallback reached");

                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Media loaded successfully");
                } else {
                     Log.e(TAG, "Error loading Media : " + result.getStatus().getStatusCode() );
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Problem opening media during loading", e);
    }
}
```

## Expected behaviour :

I basically first call *createMediaPlayer()* once, then call *loadMedia(...)*. The first call to *loadMedia* will **show nothing in the log : nor success or fail**. Next calls issue with errorCode 4.

I get the *load* event on the receiver side. But, back to the sender side, I can't manage to end the load phase and get a *media session* to be created.
I was expecting *sendLoadComplete()* to do so but I might be wrong. How can I have the media status to update and the loadMedia ResultCallback to be reached ?

My goal is to use *RemoteMediaPlayer.play()*, *pause()*, ... but for now I get stuck with *'No current media session'* because the media isn't loaded yet.

Also, I'd really enjoy to be able to log any message the Sender receives, before being processed. Is it possible ?

Hope I did not forget any information,
Thanks for your help !

**edit:** I solved this by using a custom message channel since it seems that I can't use RemoteMediaPlayer the way I want to.

Comment: The Cast receiver SDK Media Manager only works with a HTML media element.

Comment: This is bad news ! :( The documentation states that mediaElement can be _"The DOM media element or a player that implements the cast.receiver.media.Player interface."_, but it seems that class doesn't exist anymore... Any advice on how I could use RemoteMediaPlayer without a mediaElement ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error code 4 you are receiving is bogus; see https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JimRenkel2014/posts/aY5RP7X3QhA . As noted there, I created a Chromecast issue for this (https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=305&thanks=305&ts=1403833532). Additional support for this issue will help it get fixed faster! :-)

Comment: Hi Jim, the errorCode here does not surprise me because happening only when I call _load_ multiple times (See Ali Naddaf's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23877967/1496236).
My problem is that the first call never gives any result !

Answer (score 0):

`.sendLoadComplete(true)`

The boolean value helped me to receive the loaded event on sender. Might help you as well.